# Creating Custom List View Like Native Android SMS App

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-custom-view

Hi im trying to create a custom layout for my app, can any body guide me how i can achieve the design like the native android sms app

[image]

Answer (score 1):

look at this example it will help you

example 1 : [android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

example 2 : [How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)